# Can you influence the traits your 'family' gets?

Tags: rogue-legacy

In Rogue Legacy, I seem to get some traits popping up more frequently than others, which also seems to coincide with traits I repeatedly pick.

Does the game take into consideration your 'preferred' traits, and make those slightly more common? Or is it just completely random and I've happened across something that is statistically unlikely?

So my question is, if I repeatedly pick a trait, will it become more common?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Traits are determined by their "rarity" - http://rogue-legacy.wikia.com/wiki/Traits_Breakdown

The higher the rarity, the harder the trait is to acquire. There's no way that you can influence which traits your family gets.

---

There is a 94% chance that a champion will have at least 1 trait, and a 55% chance that a champion will have 2 traits.

The game makes a "dice roll" to determine which rarity of traits to select from.

- 50% chance to be level 1
- 36% chance to be level 2
- 14% chance to be level 3

The game then gathers all of the traits with the given rarity and randomly selects one of those traits to give the player.

The game also checks for trait conflicts, which means the following will not occur:

- Muscle Wk. and Hypergonadism
- Endomorph and Ectomorph
- Gigantism and Dwarfism
- Near-sighted and Far-sighted
- Color Blind and Nostalgic

The game also ensures the same trait isn't selected twice.

Comment: Perfect, just what i was looking for, thanks, just so happens that the traits i kept choosing were also the ones with the highest percentage chance of being picked!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Randomize Children upgrade gives you a single reroll of all 3 children anytime you start a new legacy.